# Supremum over a sequence with two indices

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

Let $(a_{nm})_{n,m=1}^\infty \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that

\begin{equation}
\sup_{n}\sup_{m}a_{nm} = \sup_{m}\sup_{n}a_{nm}   
\end{equation}

This is a practice question for a test that I'm not really sure where to start. It seems fairly obvious, but I don't know what to do to make it rigorous.

Comment: Let $A=(a_{nm})\subset \mathbb{R}$. Hence both supremums coincide with $\sup_{x\in A} x=\sup A$.

Comment: @Milly: The question was how to make it rigorous...

Answer (score 3):

You have $a_{mn} \le \sup_{n'} a_{mn'}$ for all $m,n$, hence
$a_{mn} \le \sup_{m'}\sup_{n'} a_{m'n'}$ for all $m,n$.
Then $\sup_m a_{mn} \le \sup_{m'}\sup_{n'} a_{m'n'}$ for all $n$ and so
$\sup_n \sup_m a_{mn} \le \sup_{m'}\sup_{n'} a_{m'n'}$.

Now repeat the argument with the order switched.

Answer (score 1):

We could just as easily make Milly's idea from the comment section rigorous:
$$a_{mn}\leq \sup_{n'} a_{mn'}\leq \sup_{m'}\sup_{n'} a_{m'n'}\Rightarrow \sup_{m,n }a_{mn}\leq\sup_{m'}\sup_{n'} a_{m'n'} $$

Similarly:

$$a_{mn}\leq \sup_{m,n} a_{mn}\Rightarrow \sup_{n'}a_{m n'}\leq \sup_{m,n}a_{mn }\Rightarrow \sup_{m'}\sup_{n'} a_{m'n'}\leq \sup_{m,n} a_{mn}$$

Therefore, $\sup_{m,n}a_{m,n}=\sup_m \sup_n a_{m,n}$. Identical argument for the $\sup$ taken in inverted order.